# Set other language than English as default in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I have read many articles from stackoverflow and this doesnt help me. So i try to change language by default.

I changed info.plist like this:

[image]

Also i have changed this settings

[image]

and i changed language on storyboard

[image]

So i still have english by default. Please give me some advice how i can change language by default. Why its so hurt to change language by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Run options App Language

[image]

Comment: Are you asking or providing a solution?

Comment: thanks for the answer. When i run project from xcode everething is fine(language by default is another - not english). 
Then i upload current build to test flight, and when i installed from test flight my default language bacame english((( How i can change default language from test flight too?